# MVC Java Config - HandlerInterceptor not excluding paths

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-3

I have a MVC Java configuration but the `HandlerInterceptor` is not excluding some patterns.

At the line marked with **xxx**, if

1) I add both `addPatterns("/**")` and `excludePathPatterns("*.ecxld")` to the `HandlerInterceptor`'s `InterceptorRegistration`, the `HandlerInterceptor.preHanlde()` is NOT invoked at all. e.g `.addPathPatterns("/**").excludePathPatterns("*.ecxld")`

2) I add only `excludePathPatterns("*.ecxld")` to the `HandlerInterceptor`'s `InterceptorRegistration`, the `HandlerInterceptor.preHanlde()` is still executed.

(the other interceptors are invoked fine).

Any pointers appreciated.

Thanks

```
@Configuration
public class MyMVCConfigurerAdapter extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

 @Override
 public void addInterceptors(final InterceptorRegistry registry) {

     registry.addInterceptor(getInterceptorOne());

     registry.addInterceptor(getMyHandlerInterceptor())
                 .excludePathPatterns("*.ecxld");  // **xxx**

     registry.addInterceptor(getInterceptorTwo()
     );

 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After debugging, the interceptors are not executed in the order they were added.  In the above example, interceptorOne, then interceptorTwo, then the handler (with the excluded pattern) was executed.

Answer (score 13):

The patterns you specify for include and exclude are ant bases [path expressions](http://ant.apache.org/manual/dirtasks.html#patterns) and not normal URL expressions as you would express in web.xml to map a servlet or filter for instance.

To make an exclude work you have to also include an include path (as you already noticed with your second remark). Next change your exclude pattern to `/**/*.ecxld`.

Your current expression `*.ecxld` would match `file.ecxld` but it will not match `/file.ecxld` or even `/foo/file.ecxld`. The `/**/` part takes care of that. However to make it work it also requires an `includePathExpression` (the code [checks](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-webmvc/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/servlet/config/annotation/InterceptorRegistration.java#L72) if there is an `includePathExpression` when not it is ignoring the `excludePathExpression`).

So in short change your configuration to the following should solve your problem.

```
@Configuration
public class MyMVCConfigurerAdapter extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

 @Override
 public void addInterceptors(final InterceptorRegistry registry) {

     registry.addInterceptor(getInterceptorOne());

     registry.addInterceptor(getMyHandlerInterceptor())
                 .includePathPatterns("/**")
                 .excludePathPatterns("/**/*.ecxld");  

     registry.addInterceptor(getInterceptorTwo()
     );

 }
```

Comment: thanks for your comment.  I've tried this.  But it still doesn't exclude the path from the preHandle.  ps the method to add patterns is `.addPathPatterns()`

Comment: Strange it works in my testcase, if I simply try the match. Enable DEBUG or TRACE logging and check what is happening during request processing.

Comment: For me too, same issue. Tried all above .. but it does not works.

Answer (score 2):

I know this was a long while ago but I just stumbled over the same problem. During my search I found the following [blog](http://www.jacobquatier.com/posts/2013/07/15/spring-mvc-mapped-interceptors/). There it is mentioned that if the interceptors are configured as beans they will be automatically added to the chain.
I am now using Spring 4.1.x so there might be a difference but what solved it for me was the following:

1. (I tried to avoid defining them as a spring beans. It didn't help.)
2. I configured the interceptors as spring beans (so I could autowire stuff into them [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18218386/cannot-autowire-service-in-handlerinterceptoradapter))
3. I changed my definition as follows:

   registry.addInterceptor(getMyHandlerInterceptor())
   .addPathPatterns("/**")
   .excludePathPatterns("/user/login");

By putting the addPathPatterns before the excludePathPatterns the behavior of the interceptor suddenly worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

I run into this trouble, can't exclude the path.
After I debug, found out is because Spring security redirect to "/login", because of "/login" is included in "/**", that why cannot access.

Solution is add the login & logout link as exclude paths too!

Answer (score 0):

I've faced a similar problem while working with SpringBoot.

**How I solved this problem?**

I made a method to return a new instance of the Interceptor. And you will have to write the excludePathPatters after the addPathPattern method of the registry.

Here's the code snippet:

```
@Bean
public AuthInterceptor getAuthInterceptor() {
    return new AuthInterceptor();
}

@Override
public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
    registry.addInterceptor(**getAuthInterceptor()**)
        .addPathPatterns("/**")
        .excludePathPatterns("/login/**");
}
```

I hope this helps.