# Cannot Inject Service in HandlerInterceptorAdapter, Getting NullPointerException

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, interceptor

I have a service-client project which is in normal spring application , not spring boot .its used for mainly logging related things.which contains Interceptor , loggingservice impl class and some model classes for logging. I have added this module as a dependency to main application in `pom.xml`.and i was able to inject and use the loggingService beans within the service layers of the main application.

Am getting `NullPointerException` while auto-wiring loggingService within the interceptor .The bean is not available within the interceptor.but like i said it can be injected and used within the main application.
Also am not able to read properties using `@Value` within the interceptor.

This is my Interceptor class .

```
@Component
public class LoggingInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {

    @Autowired
    LoggingService loggingService;


    @Override
    public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object object) throws Exception {
        loggingService.info("Am in prehandle");
        return true;
    }
}
```

This is my configuration class where i register the interceptor with the main application

```
@Component
public class LoggingConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
        registry.addInterceptor(getLoginInterceptor());
    }

    @Bean
    public LoggingInterceptor getLoginInterceptor() {
        return new LoggingInterceptor();
    }

}
```

My question is almost similar to this post [Cannot Autowire Service in HandlerInterceptorAdapter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18218386/cannot-autowire-service-in-handlerinterceptoradapter/) , but its different like am referring the interceptor from another module , and like they suggested i tried to create the bean from the application.
But the issues am facing right now is

1. getting `NullPointerException` while injecting loggingService within interceptor, but its working in main application
2. `@Value` annotation also return null, not able to read from properties

Comment: Chanage `@Component` to `@Configuration`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 possible solutions.

1. Mark your `LoggingConfig` as `@Configuration` instead of `@Copmponent`
2. Inject the `LoggingInterceptor` instead of referencing the `@Bean` method

### Option 1: `LoggingConfig` as `@Configuration`

Your `LoggingConfig` is marked as an `@Component` whereas it should be marked as an `@Configuration`. The difference is that whilst it is allowed to have an `@Bean` method on an `@Component` it operates in a so-called [lite mode](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#beans-java-basic-concepts). Meaning you cannot use method references to get the instance of a bean (this is due to no special proxy being created). This will lead to just a new instance of the `LoggingInterceptor` being created but it isn't a bean.

So in short what you are doing is equivalent to `registry.addInterceptor(new LoggingInterceptor());` which just creates an instance without Spring knowing about it.

When marking the `LoggingConfig` as an `@Configuration` a special proxy will be created which will make the `LoggingInterceptor` a proper singleton bean, due to the method call being intercepted. This will register the bean in Spring and you will be able call the method.

**NOTE:** You actually endup with 2 instances of the `LoggingInterceptor` one due to the `@Component` on it the other through the `@Bean`. Remove the `@Component`.

### Option 2: Inject the `LoggingInterceptor`.

As your `LoggingInterceptor` is marked as an `@Component` Spring will already create an instance (you actually have 2 instances of it created in your current setup). This instance you can inject into your `LoggingConfig`.

```
@Component
public class LoggingConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    private LoggingInterceptor loggingInterceptor;

    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
        registry.addInterceptor(loggingInterceptor);
    }
}
```

With this you can remove the `@Bean` method as you will get the proper one injected into your `LoggingConfig` class. The class can also remain an `@Component` in this case. Although I would recommend using `@Configuration` as to also properly stereotype it.

**NOTE:** If you are on a recent Spring version you can use `@Configuration(proxyBeanMethods=false)`. This will make a lite-configuration (just like an `@Component`) but it is still marked properly as a configuration class.

Comment: Thanks @M.Deinum , Its Worked